# How to use -r header in cleos

Tags: cleos

What's the purpose to have Options `-r` in `cleos`?

in version v1.1.3, there is a `-r` or `--header`:

> pass specific HTTP header, repeat this option to pass multiple headers

Is there any example to demonstrate how header works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explanation is provided [in the pull request](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/3323):

> In some scenarios, 'nodeos' runs remotely from where 'cleos' locates,
>   that implies the communication between the two parties should go
>   across the network. So a new option '-r,--header' is proposed in this
>   PR to allow user to customized the HTTP request headers sent by
>   'cleos' in case that some 'middle' devices may require for specific
>   headers to contain some 'token'.
>
> And also, if 'nodeos' is set up to provide HTTPS APIs, say by placing
>   a reverse proxy in front, in many cases, especially for some testing
>   environments, there might not be domains assigned with the 'nodeos' -
>   so 'cleos' needs a way to 'tolerate' with the invalid certificates. To
>   address this, a new option '-n,--no-verify' is proposed in this PR
>   too, to disable the peer verification for current secure connection.